# how to get json data form below format using angularJs 1.6

Tags: arrays, angularjs, json

**How can I access the JSON data below format: To get JSON data like id et.al**

```
 [
    {
    id: 10,
    hotelName: "TajBanjara",
    pricePerNight: 200.23,
    nbOfNights: 3,
    totalPrice: 600.6899999999999
    },
    {
    id: 11,
    hotelName: "TajKrishna",
    pricePerNight: 90.23,
    nbOfNights: 2,
    totalPrice: 180.46
    },
    {
    id: 12,
    hotelName: "Novatel",
    pricePerNight: 100.23,
    nbOfNights: 3,
    totalPrice: 300.69
    }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

> var data = [ { id: 10, hotelName: "TajBanjara", pricePerNight: 200.23,
>   nbOfNights: 3, totalPrice: 600.6899999999999 }, { id: 11, hotelName:
>   "TajKrishna", pricePerNight: 90.23, nbOfNights: 2, totalPrice: 180.46
>   }, { id: 12, hotelName: "Novatel", pricePerNight: 100.23, nbOfNights:
>   3, totalPrice: 300.69 } ]

and you can get the id value as
***`data[0].id`*** for the first object in json array.